# Kubernetes NFS Server is not reachable via Service endpoint

Tags: kubernetes, nfs

I have deployed NFS Server using following manifest

```
---

kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-pv-provisioning-demo
  namespace: nfs
  labels:
    role: nfs-server
spec:
  storageClassName: aws-gp3
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 10Gi

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
  namespace: nfs
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      role: nfs-server
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        role: nfs-server
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nfs-server
        image: registry.k8s.io/volume-nfs:0.8
        ports:
          - name: nfs
            containerPort: 2049
          - name: mountd
            containerPort: 20048
          - name: rpcbind
            containerPort: 111
        securityContext:
          privileged: true
        volumeMounts:
          - mountPath: /exports
            name: mypvc
      volumes:
        - name: mypvc
          persistentVolumeClaim:
            claimName: nfs-pv-provisioning-demo

---

kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: nfs-server
  namespace: nfs
spec:
  ports:
    - name: nfs
      port: 2049
    - name: mountd
      port: 20048
    - name: rpcbind
      port: 111
  selector:
    role: nfs-server

---
```

But when I use `nfs-server.nfs.svc.cluster.local` for Server name it failed to resolved it. It worked when I use Cluster IP for Service endpoint.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: nfs
  namespace: nfs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 1Mi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  nfs:
    server: nfs-server.nfs.svc.cluster.local
    # server: 172.20.144.30
    path: "/"
  mountOptions:
    - nfsvers=4.2
```

Any idea what is wrong with this setup ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known bug in Kubernetes : probably an initialization problem where the NFS server is set up before the pod can reach the internal DNS.

Dirty solution : if you want to keep the `nfs-server.nfs.svc.cluster.local`, you can edit the /etc/hosts file on each node with the `nfs-server.nfs.svc.cluster.local` next to the IP :

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
##
# Host Database
#
# localhost is used to configure the loopback interface
# when the system is booting.  Do not change this entry.
##
127.0.0.1       localhost
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1             localhost
172.20.144.30   nfs-server.nfs.svc.cluster.local
```

You can find more info here : https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/3417 or by Googling `server: nfs-server.nfs.svc.cluster.local`